# Should I wait for some time to be verified by google to see Ads in my page?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, iframe, adsense

Here is my code:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxx" data-ad-slot="xxx"></ins>
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>
```

I am using wordpress. So created test page and placed code inside of content and also tried to place code directly in php template file. But in 2 cases no success, iframe body is empty and nothing appears in the website. Should I wait for some time to be verified by google or it is another issue that I can't see Ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this useful article https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9715?hl=en and yes, I need to wait until google completed review of site.